# th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}" causes Exception evaluating SpringEL expression

Tags: spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I'm trying to do validation on 1 field of the form as you guys can see:

```html
<div id ="EditModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <form class="modal-dialog" th:action="@{/Edit}" th:object="${person1}" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="edit-modal-person-id" name="id" value=""/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="edit-modal-person-name" name="name"/>
                <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" th:class="'error'">something</p>
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="PhoneNumberEdit">Edit Phone Number</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="SubmitEdit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

the attribute `th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"` always causes the 500 error for me.

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editPerson(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="person1") PersonRequest person, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:All";
    }
    else {
        personService.update(person.getId(), person.getName());
        return "redirect:All";
    }
}
```

my entity:

```
public class PersonRequest {

    @NotNull
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Name
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public PersonRequest() {
        super();
    }
}
```

the console return this following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'person1' available as request attribute.
```

But I think that doesnt have anything to do with this because if I remove p tag it runs normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you make a redirect, (you make a "redirect:All").
Because of the redirect, you do not pass object person1 thus the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'person1' available as request attribute".

If you want post the code of the /all requestMapping that you have

Probably you want something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editPerson(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="person1") PersonRequest person, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {

            return "edit";//change it to the name of the html page that you want to go
        }
        else {
            //probably here you return in the page with all the persons 
            personService.update(person.getId(), person.getName());
            return "redirect:All";
        }
    }
```