# How evaluating fields from nested object in thymeleaf template?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Given two objects:

```
public class MVCmodel {
   UUID uuid;
   NestedObject nestedObject = new NestedObject ();
}

public class NestedObject {
   @Size(min = 2, max = 99)
   String name = "";
}
```

thymeleaf template

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <input required="true" type="text" th:name="name"
                           th:value="${mVCmodel.getNestedObject.getName()}"
                   >
                   <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
                    th:errors="${mVCmodel.getNestedObject().getName()}"
                   >Name Error
                   </span> 
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I get this Error:
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "fields.hasErrors('name')"

SpringEL tries to evaluat mVCmodel.name and must fail because there is no field name in MVCmodel.

How to evaluate the field mVCmodel.nestedObject.name?

Comment: there is a wrongly formatted td tag. watch out

Comment: thx
fixed: (td> -> <td>)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}" causes Exception evaluating SpringEL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169664/thif-fields-haserrors-causes-exception-evaluating-springel-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Your class NestedObject has no field named 'name'.

Comment: FYI look like it has

Answer (score 0):

If [you're not using in a form using `th:object`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#displaying-errors-outside-forms), you need to use `#fields.hasErrors` like this:

```
${#fields.hasErrors('${mVCmodel.nestedObject.name}')}
```

If you are using `th:object`, something like this should work:

```
${#fields.hasErrors('nestedObject.name')}
```

Difficult to tell from the code you posted.  Do you have getters and setters for each of your fields?